# Plot with conditional colors based on values in R

Tags: r, colors, plot, ggplot2

I want to plot a graph with different colors based on values. I wrote the below code,

```
np_graph <- data.frame(C1 = -5:5, C2 = -5:5)
x=np_graph2$C1
y=np_graph2$C2
plot(x,y,xlab="PC1",ylab="PC2")
```

Now, if the value of X is >0, then that value should be in green (in the graph). if the value of Y is >0, then that value should be in red (in the graph).

Can some one help me in this?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

The argument `col` will set the colours, you could use this in conjunction with an `ifelse` statement. See `?plot` for more details.

```
# using base plot
plot(x,y,xlab="PC1",ylab="PC2", col = ifelse(x < 0,'red','green'), pch = 19 )
```

[image]

To do the same thing in `ggplot2`.

```
#using ggplot2
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(np_graph) + geom_point(aes(x = C1, y = C2, colour = C1 >0)) +
  scale_colour_manual(name = 'PC1 > 0', values = setNames(c('red','green'),c(T, F))) +
  xlab('PC1') + ylab('PC2')
```

[image]

Comment: +1 very nice. Also for showing the newby how to make a reproducible example.

Comment: @mnel very nice answer. Although I have a question to you. If I want to put up range of values like x > 1 & y > 2 then green color, x < 1 & y > 2 then red color and the rest of the points in gray color. How will I be able to accomplish it?

Comment: @aarn -- a couple of nested `ifelse` statements should do it. eg ` col = ifelse(x>1&y>1,'red', ifelse(x<1&y>2,'green','grey'))`

Comment: @mnel what if you have three conditions?

Answer (score 13):

Alternatively, in `ggplot2`, you can set a new column "Color" based on the ifelse statement and then use `scale_color_identity` to apply those color on the graph:

```r
np_graph %>% mutate(Color = ifelse(C1 > 0, "green", "red")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = C1, y= C2, color = Color))+
  geom_point()+
  scale_color_identity()
```

[image]