# R - stuck with plot() - Colouring shapefile polygons based upon a slot value

Tags: r, geospatial, shapefile

I have a shapefile showing remote areas in Australia, obtained from the Australian Bureau of Statistics:

http://www.abs.gov.au/AUSSTATS/abs@.nsf/DetailsPage/1270.0.55.005July%202011?OpenDocument

At the same URL is a PDF "ASGS Remoteness Structure Edition 2011 PDF Maps" - I am trying to reproduce the first map from this PDF document.

I have read in the shapefile and added colour information to the `data` slot:

```
ra <- readShapeSpatial("RA_2011_AUST", delete_null_obj = TRUE)
ra@data$COLOUR <- "#FFFFFF"
ra@data$COLOUR[(as.numeric(as.character(ra@data$RA_CODE11)) %% 10) == 0] <- "#006837"
ra@data$COLOUR[(as.numeric(as.character(ra@data$RA_CODE11)) %% 10) == 1] <- "#31A354"
ra@data$COLOUR[(as.numeric(as.character(ra@data$RA_CODE11)) %% 10) == 2] <- "#78C679"
ra@data$COLOUR[(as.numeric(as.character(ra@data$RA_CODE11)) %% 10) == 3] <- "#C2E699"
ra@data$COLOUR[(as.numeric(as.character(ra@data$RA_CODE11)) %% 10) == 4] <- "#FFFFCC"
```

The only thing left for me to do is plot the map! This is where I get stuck...

`ra@polygons` is a list of 35 polygons, each of which has a slot `ID` which is an index to the data frame `ra@data`. So all I have to do is tell `plot()` to find the colour in `ra@data$COLOUR[ID]`. Well, not quite. Each of the 35 polygons (class "Polygons") has its own list of polygons (class "Polygon"); in total there are 6902 polygons!!!

My understanding of `plot()` is that I have to pass it a vector of colours in the same order as the polygons will be plotted. Therefore I believe I will have to create a vector of length 6902 with each element holding the colour value for the associated polygon. How am I doing so far?

That would be easy enough if the polygons were plotted in order, but they aren't. Each of the 35 Polygons has a slot `plotOrder` which is an integer vector, so the colour vector will, presumably, have to be ordered by the values in each of these vectors.

At this point this all seems a bit too complex. Am I completely off track here?

Thanks for your advice!

Comment: You should read shapefiles using readOGR from the rgdal package, and that will load in the projection data if there's a .prj file with the shapefile.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You did all the work already!

```
plot(ra, col=ra@data$COLOUR)
```

Or even, as @Spacedman suggested:

```
plot(ra, col=ra$COLOUR)
```

And that's it!

[image]

And if you want to get rid of the polygon borders:

```
plot(ra, col=ra$COLOUR, border=NA)
```

[image]

**Edit**: an attempt to explain this behaviour:

According to `?SpatialPointsDataFrame`:

> SpatialPolygonsDataFrame with default ID matching checks the data frame row names against the Polygons ID slots. They must then agree with each other, and be unique (no Polygons objects can share IDs); the data frame rows will be re-ordered if needed to match the Polygons IDs..

Meaning that the polygons are ordered according to their ID and hence are in the order of the rows of the dataframe in the slot `@data`.

Now if you look at the function `plot.SpatialPolygons` (using `getAnywhere(plot.SpatialPolygons)`) there are those lines at some point:

```
...
    polys <- slot(x, "polygons")
    pO <- slot(x, "plotOrder")
    if (!is.null(density)) {
        if (missing(col)) 
            col <- par("fg")
        if (length(col) != n) 
            col <- rep(col, n, n)
        if (length(density) != n) 
            density <- rep(density, n, n)
        if (length(angle) != n) 
            angle <- rep(angle, n, n)
        for (j in pO) .polygonRingHoles(polys[[j]], border = border[j], 
            xpd = xpd, density = density[j], angle = angle[j], 
            col = col[j], pbg = pbg, lty = lty, ...)
    }
...
```

The vector inputted to `col` has the same order as the `polygons` slot and hence as ID. `plotOrder` is used to index all of them in the same way.

Comment: Just `ra$COLOUR` should work - spatial data frames work mostly like data frames except when they dont...

Comment: OK, that's pretty cool! But why does it work? Aren't the polygons plotted in the order specified by ra@plotOrder??? This solution only works if they're plotted in numerical order, ignoring ra@plotOrder.

Comment: And what about the 6902 "leaf" polygons? I guess this is just how the plot() method is implemented for this class, but it's not obvious that it should be this way.

Comment: @MichaelHenry Read [this](http://www.amazon.com/o/ASIN/0387781706). If you're serious about GIS in R it is well worth the time invested.

Comment: @MichaelHenry I'm not an expert but I think it works for the same reason each one of your polygons are associated with values of `RA_NAME11` or `STE_NAME11`: basically each row of your dataframe `ra@data` has an ID (the rownames) and each cluster of polygon (`ra@polygons`) has a reference to that ID (for instance `ra@polygons[[1]]@ID` for the first cluster). The "leaf" polygons don't because they depend on their "root" polygon cluster.

Comment: @MichaelHenry so to summarize the order of the vector that we pass to `col` is linked to the order of the IDs not to the plotting order. I think...