# How can I plot a SpatialPolygonDataframe variable?

Tags: r, plot, geospatial, spatial, raster

I have a SPDF of this type:

```
class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
features    : 11723 
extent      : -2294145, -1102155, 2191605, 3506145  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0 
variables   : 10
names       : OBJECTID,    POI_ID, PROD_UNIT, Y_Centroid, X_Centroid,   AREA, seg_id,   Avg, Lon_Centro, Lat_Centro
```

When I plot it using `plot(spdf)`, I get the polygons.

But I want to color these polygons using one of the variables (say, AREA).

I know how to do it using `spplot`, but I want to use baseplot as it is much faster. How can I do this?

This is how I would do it using `spplot`:

```
spplot(SPDF, "AREA", main = "area (m2)")
```

Answer (score 2):

This is possible within base R, but not the most user-friendly. It works easiest if you save the colour you want to be plotted as a column within the dataset.

Here is a reproducible dataset:

```
library(maptools)
setwd(system.file("shapes", package="maptools"))
columbus <- readShapeSpatial("columbus.shp")
plot(columbus)
```

[image]

There are a total of 49 shapefiles in this case, so I am going to just assign a random palette of 7 colours:

```
columbus$colour <- rep(c("red", "blue", "green", "orange", "pink", "grey", "yellow"),7)
plot(columbus, col=columbus$colour)
```

[image]

If you wanted to assign a colour range, you can check out this answer here: [R - stuck with plot() - Colouring shapefile polygons based upon a slot value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745815/r-stuck-with-plot-colouring-shapefile-polygons-based-upon-a-slot-value)