# Change Line Colors Above Specific Values

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library(ggplot2)
data = data.frame("person"=rep(1:2,4),
                  "time" = rep(1:4, 2),
                  "scores" = c(5,7,9,11,
                               8,12,13,14))
data = data[order(data$person),]

ggplot(data,aes(time,scores,group=as.factor(person))) +
  geom_line(color="red")
```

This code here will plot the two lines in red. I understand it how to change the color of a line. But~ how do I edit code so values of 8 and more are colored blue?

**edit**

eipi10 provided a great answer but I realize it only works when you have a single if statement, What if you have data such as

```
library(ggplot2)
data = data.frame("person"=c(rep(1,4), rep(2,4)),
                  "time" = rep(1:4, 2),
                  "scores" = c(5,7,9,11,
                               8,12,13,14),
                  "type" = c(1,2,2,3,
                             1,1,3,3))
data = data[order(data$person),]
```

And you want:
1. Red if type = 1
2. Blue if type = 2
3. Green if type = 3

Also I changed this question. The original is above and then I added this extra pieces which some could be very useful for.!

Comment: `geom_line(aes(color=scores > 8)) + scale_colour_manual(values=c(\`TRUE\`="blue", \`FALSE\`="red"))`

Comment: `geom_line(colour = ifelse(data$scores > 8, "blue", "red"))`

Comment: @d.b I think eipi10's solution may be safer because it does not use `$` (which could potentially not match the order of the data frame which is being plotted). Anyways. It's a dupe question...

Comment: @eipi10 check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11838396/7941188) from mnel, similar to yours, but with the elegant use of `setNames`

Comment: as to your edit - if you want to color by your type, just use ggplots basic syntax `geom_line(aes(color = type))+scale_color_manual(values = etc)`