# Different bar color for positive and negative bars in bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to have a bar plot that colors the bars red if the numbers are positive and green if the numbers are negative. I want this to be in the form of a ggplot "template" where I can change the underlying data and it still does what I want. Currently my code only works if all the numbers are positive or if there are positive and negative numbers in my data.

Version 1 (does not work). All bars should be green, however, since there are no positive numbers the `fill = change < 0` does not work and it takes just the first color which is red in this case.

```
data1 <- data.frame(group = as.factor(c("all", "men", "women")),
                   change = as.numeric(c(-10000, -6000, -4000)))

ggplot(data1, 
       aes(x = group, 
           y = change, 
           fill = change < 0)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  scale_fill_manual(guide = FALSE,
                    values = c("red", "green"))
```

Version 2 (works as expected).

```
data2 <- data.frame(group = as.factor(c("all", "men", "women")),
                    change = as.numeric(c(2000, 6000, -4000)))

ggplot(data2, 
       aes(x = group, 
           y = change, 
           fill = change < 0)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  scale_fill_manual(guide = FALSE,
                    values = c("red", "green"))
```

Version 3 (works - by chance?). All bars are red but I guess as in Version 1 this is only the case because red comes first in the colors specified in `scale_fill_manual`?

```
data3 <- data.frame(group = as.factor(c("all", "men", "women")),
                    change = as.numeric(c(10000, 6000, 4000)))

ggplot(data3, 
       aes(x = group, 
           y = change, 
           fill = change < 0)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  scale_fill_manual(guide = FALSE,
                    values = c("red", "green"))
```

How can I specify the bar color to make it work as I want, regardless if I use data1, data2 or data3 as an input?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible way is to define a color column based on an `ifelse` statement and then use `scale_fill_identity` to apply corresponding color:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
data2 %>% mutate(Color = ifelse(change <0, "red","green")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = group, y = change, fill = Color))+
  geom_col()+
  scale_fill_identity(guide = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: nice. Would you mind considering to add / transfer this to the main questoin, to which this here is a duplicate?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11838278/plot-with-conditional-colors-based-on-values-in-r/11838396#11838396

Comment: I would like to but on the example of the question you are referring, the color code does not make sense. There is no way to get the green color based on the example

Comment: Although I don't understnad what you exactly mean - I've seen you have added your answer. +2 (here and there ;)

Comment: ;) I did but I wa srefering to what the OP asked on the other question: "if the value of X is >0, then that value should be in green ... if the value of Y is >0, then that value should be in red". Based on the example, all values should be red if we apply the correct `ifelse` statement. I assumed it was a typo when writing the question.

Comment: Funny I haven't even noticed that, as apparently has not @mnel in their great answer. Weird condition - I am not sure if this was really a typo.

Comment: If not, the example is not adapted to this particular statement. As the question is from 2012, I believed the OP has been satisfy by @mnel's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using the SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11838396/5269252) and adapting it slightly for your case gives this way of using `scale_fill_manual` to get what you want:

```r
library(ggplot2)

data1 <- data.frame(group = as.factor(c("all", "men", "women")),
                    change = as.numeric(c(-10000, -6000, -4000)))

data2 <- data.frame(group = as.factor(c("all", "men", "women")),
                    change = as.numeric(c(2000, 6000, -4000)))

data3 <- data.frame(group = as.factor(c("all", "men", "women")),
                    change = as.numeric(c(10000, 6000, 4000)))

myplot <- function(df){
    ggplot(df, 
           aes(x = group, 
               y = change, 
               fill = change < 0)) + 
        geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
        scale_fill_manual(guide = FALSE,
                          name = 'change < 0', 
                          values = setNames(c('green', 'red'), c(T, F)))
}

myplot(data1)
```

[image]

```r
myplot(data2)
```

[image]

```r
myplot(data3)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-01-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>