# How to plot different colors (based on condition) with ggmap (R)?

Tags: r, colors, maps, conditional-statements, ggmap

similar to a couple questions, but I have a couple of issues that come up that are unique. (I tried using code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11838278/plot-with-conditional-colors-based-on-values-in-r) but it doesn't work for me due to potentially using ggmap instead of ggplot).

I am trying to plot a map with point color changes based on whether plants are infected (1) or not infected (0) with a pathogen. Even better, I would like to change color of points (pathogen status) *and*  shape of points based on plant species (there are 2).

My columns are 
Sample name, plant species (a or b), lat, lon, pathogen status (0 or 1)

created a map (just an example coordinate used for how i would make the map)
`map <- get_googlemap(center = c(lon = -111.348284, lat = 38.484637), zoom = 15, maptype = "satellite")`

then here's the code. it works as is, but i cannot figure out where to put the conditional statement. I used colors from a national parks pallete.

```
  ggtitle("Distribution of pathogen") + 
  theme_void() + 
    geom_point(data = data, mapping = aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude), color = "#7397CB", size=1) +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(colour = "#554C6C") , 
    panel.border = element_rect((colour = "#70646E"), fill=NA, size=2)
    )
```

If this has been answered before (which I have checked other questions, but none relate to ggmap, or that x and y values are **not** what i want to be the reason for color change) please link!
Thanks -T

Answer (score 1):

Use color as an aesthetic and set to pathogen status, and add shape aesthetic set to species:

```
 ggtitle("Distribution of pathogen") + 
  theme_void() + 
    geom_point(data = data, mapping = aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude,
      color=PathogenStatus, shape=Species), size=1) +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(colour = "#554C6C") , 
    panel.border = element_rect((colour = "#70646E"), fill=NA, size=2)
    )
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks for your fast response. Here's a follow-up question. Where (how) do I type the code to let it know what shape and what colors to use?

Comment: The standard way you would in ggplot ... see `scale_color_manual` and `scale_shape_manual`.