# Ifelse for conditional color in base R not working

Tags: r, plot

I am following this: [Plot with conditional colors based on values in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11838278/plot-with-conditional-colors-based-on-values-in-r)

I have the following code:

```
stripchart(round(df$pnl_act / round_to, 0) * round_to, 
           xlim=c(-2500,2500), 
           pch = 20, 
           method = "stack",
           xaxt = "n",
           main = paste("Act", pp1[[1]], pp2[[1]], pp3[[1]],threshold_vector[1], sep = "-"),
           col = ifelse((round(df$pnl_act / round_to, 0) * round_to) > 0, "red", "green")
           )
```

However, all my colors are green.

When I run this:

```
(round(df$pnl_act / round_to, 0) * round_to) > 0
```

I get:

```
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[20] FALSE
```

Any ideas where I went wrong?

Edit:

Here is the vector of data:

```
df$pnl_act
```

Output:

```
  [1]    0 -220 -270  -50  190 -210   90  170   50   60 -390  -50   40  410  -10 -180 -170  230 -100 -1000
```

Comment: We need an example data, provide `dput(head(myData))`.

Comment: I've included the vector of data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you can do such plotting with `ifelse` on `stripchart`. Here is an option plotting two stripcharts on top of each other with different colors.

```
x1 <- x[x > 0]
x2 <- x[x <= 0]
stripchart(x1, col = 'green', xlim = range(x))
stripchart(x2, col = 'red', add = TRUE)
```

[image]
**data**

```
x <- c(0, -220, -270, -50, 190, -210, 90, 170, 50, 60, -390, -50, 
40, 410, -10, -180, -170, 230, -100, -1000)
```

I have simplified the data and removed extra details from `stripchart` code just to explain the concept. You can add them as per your requirement.